# Will be Control.Dispose called if exception occurred in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have UserControl which creates some disposable object in PageLoad.

```
private TeWorkspace workspace; //TeWorkspace is Disposable
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   workspace = new TeWorkspace(ContextWeb);
}
```

I want use this object in whole ASP.NET lifeCycle, but I need to be sure about disposing this object at the end o lifeCycle.
So I overrided Contro.Dispose().

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    workspace.Dispose();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

My question is: whether my UserControl.Dispose will be called, if exception occurred in ASP.NET (somewhere in control lifeCycle)?

Thanks a lot

Update: So I try it and it looks like that Dispose is called when exception occurred.

Comment: You could test this and find the answer yourself.

Comment: :) OK, you are right. I can easily try it. But if you know the answer you could reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

So I try it and it looks like that Dispose is called when exception occurred.